# $f(x)=ln(x-\sqrt[3]{x^3-1})$ Finding the error and achieve higher precision

Tags: numerical-methods

> $f(x)=ln(x-\sqrt[3]{x^3-1})$ is been calculated at $x=35$ and is store in $8$ significant numbers.
>
> 1.Find the size of the error
>
> 2.Suggest a better way to achieve higher precision and find the absolute error

How should I approach it?

Comment: Taylor polynomial?

Comment: @vvnitram how will it help if I can only store 8 significant numbers?

Comment: Same [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445161), without an answer: should this be a duplicate?

Comment: It would probably helpful if you computed the values, once with rounding in every step and once with the full accuracy of your computer/calculator. Then think about applying Taylor polynomials or binomial identities, and compute again with rounding in every computation step.

Comment: @shardulc : Not exactly duplicate, since there the rounding is a mix of floating and fixed point, while here it is a clean floating point rounding.

Answer (score 1):

1. As per Taylor
   $$x-\sqrt[3]{x^3-1}=\frac1{3·x^2}+\frac1{9·x^5}+\frac{5}{81·x^8}+O(x^{-11})$$
   the difference has 3 zeros after the decimal point.
   Both terms in the difference have 2 digits before 
   the decimal point and are thus rounded to 6 digits after, 
   the difference can only have a maximum of 3 correct digits. 
   This can result in a relative error of $10^{-2}$, 
   which translates into an absolute error of that magnitude 
   in the logarithm.

   Or seen in another way, the rounding error of the root term 
   is of size $35·10^{-8}$. In the difference, this error 
   remains but is now relative to a base value of about 
   $\frac1{3·35^2}\sim\frac1{3000}$, which translates in the logarithm to 
   an absolute error of the same magnitude of about 
   $3·35^3·10^{-8}\simeq 0.0013$.

   Even that is still rather pessimistic in view of 
   the actual difference 
   of the direct evaluation `log(2.7200000e-04)=-8.2097085` 
   to the more accurate value `log(2.7211096e-04)=-8.2093006`.
2. You  can use the binomial identity
   $$
   A-B=\frac{A^3-B^3}{A^2+AB+B^2}
   $$
   using $A=x$ and $B=\sqrt[3]{x^3-1}$.

   You can also continue to use the Taylor expansion to get
   $$
   \ln(x-\sqrt[3]{x^3-1})
   =\ln(3·x^2)+\ln\left(1+\frac1{3·x^3}+O(x^{-6})\right)
   \\=\ln(3·x^2)+\frac1{3·x^3}+O(x^{-6})
   $$